# when to call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate if implementing prefersStatusBarHidden: method

Tags: ios

The documentation on hiding status bar says that I should implement this method

```
override prefersStatusBarHidden(){
    return true
}
```

and than it says: If you change the return value for this method, call the `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method. When should I call this method, in viewDidLoad, in prefersStatusBarHidden or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes you call that in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases you don't need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` at all. When your view controller appears or disappears iOS checks `prefersStatusBarHidden()` automatically.

You only need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` when the value returned by `prefersStatusBarHidden()` changes **while your view controller is visible**.